# How to prevent doctrine from creating useless migrations with DEFAULT NULL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I'd like to address question to those who use Mysql + Doctrine ORM + Doctrine migrations
I have an association:

```
    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sender;
```

(key point here is `nullable=true`. Some attributes are left behind intentionally)

1. i do `migraions:diff` - generated migration with a piece `sender_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL`
2. run migrate
3. then i do `diff` again, **expecting no new migrations** generated
4. but no, i see new file with line `CHANGE sender_id sender_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL`

It means that nothing is going to be changed, however **doctrine dbal under Mysql driver doesn't see from entity annotations that DEFAULT NULL**

I tried to add `@ORM\Column(options={"default": NULL})`.

That helped with preventing `DEFAULT NULL` in migrations, **but FK and Index** were dropped in this case.

Tried also add `columnDefinition="VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL"` but also didn't work

How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case (Symfony, using Docker with the image "mariadb:10.5.8"), the solution was to set the correct `server_version` in the config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: '5.7' # (this was previously incorrect in my setting!)
```

to

```
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.5.8' # (correct version for my setting, please adjust accordingly!)
```

Afer doing that and restarting Docker, the `diff` was empty ("No changes detected in your mapping information.").

All credit goes to the post of "tristanbes commented on Apr 4, 2018", see the following link:

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2985

Comment: It's important to note that the 'server_version' parameter can be overwritten by DATABASE_URL variable (.env or .env.load config file). You must change the 'serverVersion' parameter if exists.

DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/database?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.11

Comment: Typo error in my comment: .env or .env.local

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't make any difference when using DoctrineMigrationBundle, it keeps regenerating useless sql statements such as enum changes, dropping foreign key just to recreate them, etc...